# Making git-shell interactive

Tags: git, git-shell

I'm setting up a git server (on a RHEL 6 box).

I have created the git user and set its shell to /usr/bin/git-shell
I have created a directory git-shell-commands in the user's home (/home/git) and chmod it to 755.

I downloaded the help and list commands from github, put them in git-shell-commands and made them executable.

I also set up the .ssh directory and authorized_keys.

Now on my box when I do
ssh git@thegitserver I get the error

```
Last login: Thu Jun 13 11:56:07 2013 from 192.168.1.2
fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?
Connection to 192.168.1.3 closed.
```

What else is there to do to make it interactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a git version issue.  The version that comes with RHEL 6 (1.7.1) is too old to properly work with the git-shell-commands directory.  Upgrading to 1.8 solved this.

Answer (score -1):

The man page of git-shell describes exactly this case.
You need to create a directory called ~/git-shell-commands. In this directory you put files with the commands you want to use.

Why do you want to do this anyways?
If you want to setup a git server, [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) is the best solution I know.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have created the git-shell-commands directory and put in the help and list commands from the git repo on github.  It isn't working.  As for gitolite, I am aware of it, but really just want this limited access not anything complex like gitolite.

Comment: Gitolite isn't necessary, you can already create shared bare git repos and use linux acls, user accounts, git's pre-receive hook to make your own secure git over SSH workflow. At least, it will gives you knowledge about Git, which is useful before switching to any more advanced project.